# Subtour-gluing constraints for ILP formulation of TSPs

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, integer-programming, traveling-salesman-problem

If one doesn't want to introduce additional variables to the ILP of a TSP instance, one has to add exponentially many so-called subtour-elimination constraints; in practical calculations subtour-elimination constraints are added lazily, i.e. as subtours are encountered.
The number of subtour elimination constraints that are added after every iteration is $O(n)$.

> **Question:**
>
> if after an iteration in calculating the optimal tour via a sequence of ILPs $k$ subtours are encountered:
> wouldn't it be more efficient to
>
> - replace the $k$ subtour elimination constraints
> - with the *single* "subtour gluing constraint"
>
> that demands that summing over the variables that correspond to edges that are adjacent to two vertices from different subtours from the current set of subtours?

**Addendum:**

to clarify what kind of constraint is proposed I denote by $S_i(V_i,E_i)$ the subgraph induced by the $n_i$ vertices $V_i$ of the $i$-th subtour of the current iteration;
I further denote by $|S_i|$ the number of that subgraph's edges that are in the optimal solution of the next iteration.

With the above notation

- the classical subtour elimination constraints would be $|S_h|\,\lt\, n_h,\ h=1,\,\dots,\,k$ and
- the proposed subtour gluing constraint would be $$\sum\limits_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace: e_{ij}\ \in\ E(G)\,\setminus\,\bigcup\limits_{h=1}^k E_h}x_{ij}\quad\ge\quad k$$

Comment: Suppose $\cup_{i=1}^k S_i$ is the corresponding partition of the nodes. What is the constraint you are proposing?

Comment: @RobPratt thanks for the feedback. I have added a formal definition of the proposed constraint using a bit non-standard notation.